# Recognizing patterns in DCG

Tags: list, prolog, dcg

I am currently writing a [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg) that takes a list of form [0,1]* and tells me if the number of `0`'s in the list is `3` greater than the number of `1`'s. I can't seem to get the third part (`dcg//0`) to work.

```
 sq --> [].
 sq --> num, sq.

 num --> [0].
 num --> [1].

 dcg --> sq, dd(Count), Count > 2.

 dd(0) --> [].
 dd(Newcnt) --> [0], dd(Cnt), { Newcnt is Cnt+1 }.
 dd(Newcnt) --> [1], dd(Cnt), { Newcnt is Cnt-1 }.
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @Little Bobby Tables synthetizes (counts) elements number, and 'outside' the DCG you'll need to test the outcome

```
..., phrase(sq(Z,O), S), Z is O*3, ...
```

A simpler way could be to pass down the imbalance

```
z3o1(B) --> [1], {S is B-3}, z3o1(S).
z3o1(B) --> [0], {S is B+1}, z3o1(S).
z3o1(0) --> [].  % accept only if balanced

..., phrase(z3o1(0), S), ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost there... In fact, the code is there, let's put it to use!

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
```

Running `dd//1` with `phrase/2` we get:

```
?- C #>= 3, phrase(dd(C), Xs).
   C = 3, Xs = [0,0,0]
;  C = 4, Xs = [0,0,0,0]
;  C = 5, Xs = [0,0,0,0,0]
;  C = 6, Xs = [0,0,0,0,0,0]
;  C = 7, Xs = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
;  C = 8, Xs = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
;  C = 9, Xs = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
...
```

Where are sequences containing `1`? We know that they *must* exist ...

```
?- Xs = [0,0,0,1,0], C #>= 3, phrase(dd(C), Xs).
   Xs = [0,0,0,1,0], C = 3
;  false.
```

... but they *do not* appear in above answer sequence:

```
?- C #>= 3, phrase(dd(C), Xs), Xs = [0,0,0,1,0].
**LOOPS**
```

To force fair enumeration of the solution set, we can use a goal [`length/2`](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#length) like so:

```
?- C #>= 3, length(Xs, _), phrase(dd(C), Xs).
   C = 3, Xs = [0,0,0]
;  C = 4, Xs = [0,0,0,0]
;  C = 5, Xs = [0,0,0,0,0]
;  C = 3, Xs = [0,0,0,0,1]
;  C = 3, Xs = [0,0,0,1,0]
;  C = 3, Xs = [0,0,1,0,0]
;  C = 3, Xs = [0,1,0,0,0]
;  C = 3, Xs = [1,0,0,0,0]
;  C = 6, Xs = [0,0,0,0,0,0]
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code counts the number of zeros and ones in the given sequence. You can use it to apply any conditions you want.

```
sq(0, 0) --> [].
sq(Zeros, Ones) -->
    [0], 
    sq(Z, Ones), 
    {Zeros is Z + 1}.
sq(Zeros, Ones) -->
    [1], 
    sq(Zeros, O),
    {Ones is O + 1}.
```